# OnClick event on Popup Window in Android

Tags: android, events, popup, onclick

I am working on app where I have to show Popup within my main Activity, in Pop up I have one Button on which I need to perform some operation.

Please see my code bellow. The code does not give any error but the button click of Popup window is not working.

```
imgOpenPopup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.places);

        imgOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ConvergeActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.placepopup,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.maincam));  

                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.placepopup, null, false), 200, 265, true);

                popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.places),
                        Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


                 objbtnpopupOk=(Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnokpopup); 

                objbtnpopupOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                { 
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    { 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " hi thrtrt  " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
            }); 

            }
        });
```

Comment: Try to call popupWindow.showAtLocation... after objbtnpopupOk.setOnClickListener...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really dont know what went wrong but [this solution](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)  worked out for me.

cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.placepopup,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.maincam));  
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 200, 265, true);
```

instead this:

```
View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.placepopup,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.maincam));  
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.placepopup, null, false), 200, 265, true);
```

Comment: no button is not getting clicked. what is the problem I really dont undetrstand

Answer (score 1):

I have done it this way:

```
 popupWindow.getContentView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()...);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to lift the creation of a popup window out of the OnClickListener, and in onClick just call the method to show the popup window. It has few optimization improvements and it can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use `AlertDialog`. That will help you.Read this [Alert Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do the popup in another activity :

Add this theme to the styles file and then set it to the activity that you want to pop up in the manifest file. I am sure that the button will work in another activity.

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> 
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> 
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> 
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item> 
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: This is not what I needed. I needed Popup wiondow and need to access the controls or views of that Popup window